# Writing python script to read access log file

Tags: python, parsing, scripting

I have an accesslog file with following data format:

```
10.183.252.22 - - [18/May/2014:00:06:06 -0700] GET
/main/page_res/mon/imp?id=11062&amp;cpnsite_id=29374&amp;bid=0.3 HTTP/1.1 3
```

I need to add all bid values (which in this case is 0.3) of 3 given hours to a variable. For example, **sum of all bid values between 3 PM to 6 PM.**

**UPDATE:**
I have written the code and it is working. Now I just need to know whether this is a good way to do this or there is a better way?

OR any possible betterments in this code?

Code:

```
with open("log_file.txt") as f:
    total_bid = 0 
    while True: 
        line = f.readline() 
        string = line
        time = string.split(" ") [3]
        hour = time.split(":") [1]
        hour = int(hour)

        if hour > 6:   #no need to read logs of later hrs.
            break
        else:
            pass

        if hour >= 03 and hour < 06:
            bid_str = string.split(" ") [6]
            bid = bid_str.split (";") [2]
            bid_price = bid.split("=") [1]
            bid_price = float(bid_price)
            total_bid = total_bid + bid_price
            print total_bid 
        else: 
            pass
```

Comment: You need to make a parser, and because it's a log file and not some standard format, you'll probably have to write something custom using regular expressions.

Comment: @match an attempt has been made.

Comment: @BrendanAbel 'parser' was a great clue. It helped me writing the above code.

Comment: If there are no log times greater than 6, the loop will never end.